# Azure Elastic DB Migration: How to handle identity columns?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-elastic-scale

I have an existing sharded table with auto-increment identity column CustomerID. It appears with elastic scale you need an ID before you insert a record. How do I get the next ID from a sharded table?